# Probabilities and rpg dice goes wrong for high values

Tags: python, probability, dice

I made this short code to calculate the chances of a success rolling dice, and it worked very well... but not in big numbers. Se the code, I'll explain better below.

```
def calc_dados(f_sucessos = 1, faces = 6, n_dados = 1):

  p_max = ((f_sucessos/faces)**n_dados) #chance de todos

  fator = 1
  p_meio = 0

  for i in range(n_dados-1):
    p_meio += (((f_sucessos/faces)**(n_dados-fator) * ((faces-f_sucessos)/faces)**(n_dados-(n_dados-fator))) * n_dados)
    fator += 1

  p = p_max + p_meio
  return p*100
```

So, ok, it works, why not see how my chances are better in function of adding dice? More the dice, better the chance. So I made this tiny table with pandas:

```
f_sucessos = 1    # how many faces are success
faces = 2         # faces of the dice
n_dados = 10      # n de dados lançados

suc_list = []
for i in range(0,n_dados): suc_list.append(f_sucessos)
fac_list = []
for i in range(0,n_dados): fac_list.append(faces)
cha_list = []
for i in range(0,n_dados): cha_list.append(calc_dados(f_sucessos, faces, i+1))

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
"n_dados" : range(1,n_dados+1),
"faces" : fac_list,
"sucessos" : suc_list,
"chance" : cha_list
 }
)
df
```

The results were very strange... So I wrote an coin probability table and tested as the coin was an 2 faced dice. The right table is this:
[table of right brute force tested results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4vQr.png)

But if you use my code to create this table the result will be this:
[table of the results of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPiy.png)

Please, anybody can help me to understood why in a certain moment the probabilities just fall when they should be higher? For example:The chance of at least 1 'head' in 4 coins should be 93,75%, but my code says it is 81,25%...

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, it is recommended to include text format data in your question instead of links, see [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello people, it's finally solved!**

First I would like to thank Raibek, who solved it using combinations, I didn't realize it was solved when he did it and below I'll tell you how and why.

**If you are not following the history of this code, you just need to know that it is used to calculate the probability of getting at least ns successes when rolling d amount of dice. Solution codes are at the end of this answer.**

I found out how to solve the problem by talking to a friend, Eber, who pointed me to an alternative to check the data, anydice.com. I quickly realized that my visual check, assembling tables in Excel/Calc was wrong, but why?

Well, here comes my friend who, reading the table of large numbers with 7d6, where the error was already very evident, shows me that although at the beginning the account worked, my table did not have all the possible combinations. And the more possibilities there were, the more my accounts failed, with the odds getting smaller as more dice were added to the roll.

This is the combinations I was considering, in this example on 7d6 case.

[image: table of 7d6 combinations]

In the first code the account was:

```
successes**factor *failures**factor *d
```

The mistake is in assuming that the number of possible combinations was equal to d (which is a coincidence up to 3 dice for the tests I did before thanks to factorials of 1 = 1 and factorial of 2 = 2).

Now notice that, in 7d6 example, in the *exact 3* block there are some missing possible combinations in yellow:

[image: table of 7d6 combinations where we can find exact 3 of 1 face]

The correct account for this term of the equation is:

```
factorial(d) / factorial (failures) * factorial (successes)
```

With this account we can find out what the chance of exactly n faces rolling is, and then if we want, for example, to know the chance of at least once getting the number 1 in 3d6, we just need to add the chances of getting exactly 1 time, 2 times and 3 times. What the code already did well.

Finally, let's get to the code:

**Daniel-Eber solution:**

```
def dado(fs=1,ft=6,d=1,ns=1,exato=False):
    '''
    fs = faces sucesso
    ft = faces totais
    d  = n de dados
    ns - n de sucessos esperados modificados por exato
    exato = True: chance de exatamente ns ocorrerem, False: chance de pelo menos ns ocorrerem
    '''
    from math import factorial
    
    s =  fs/ft
    f =  (ft-fs)/ft
    d =  d
    ns =  ns
    
    p_max =  s**d
    
    falhas = 1
    po_soma = 0
    
    if exato == False:
        for i in range(d-1):
            po =  ( (s**(d-falhas)) * (f**(falhas))) * (factorial(d)/(factorial(falhas)*factorial((d-falhas))))
            po_soma += po
            falhas += 1
    else:
        p_max = 0
        falhas = d-ns
        po_soma =  ( (s**(d-falhas)) * (f**(falhas))) * (factorial(d)/(factorial(falhas)*factorial((d-falhas))))

    return f'{(p_max + po_soma)*100:.2f}%'

print(dado(1,6,6,1))
```

**Raibek solution:**

```
from scipy.special import comb


def calc_dados(f_sucessos=1, faces=6, n_dados=1):

    assert f_sucessos <= faces

    outcomes_total = faces ** n_dados

    outcomes_success = 0

    f_fail = faces - f_sucessos

    for i in range(1, n_dados + 1):

        one_permutation = (f_sucessos ** i) * (f_fail ** (n_dados - i))
        n_permutations = comb(n_dados, i)

        outcomes_success += one_permutation * n_permutations

    p = outcomes_success / outcomes_total

    return f'{(p)*100:.2f}%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't get how exactly 'calc_dados' calculate the probability of a success rolling dice.
So instead, I implemented maybe a more naive approach:

1. First, we calculate the total of possible outcomes: outcomes_total = faces ** n_dados
2. Second, we calculate the successful outcomes: outcomes_success
3. At last: p = outcomes_success / outcomes_total

I'm going to add a mathematical proof behind my version of the function a bit later:)

```
from math import comb


def calc_dados(f_sucessos=1, faces=6, n_dados=1):

    assert f_sucessos <= faces

    outcomes_total = faces ** n_dados

    outcomes_success = 0

    f_fail = faces - f_sucessos

    for i in range(1, n_dados + 1):

        one_permutation = (f_sucessos ** i) * (f_fail ** (n_dados - i))
        n_permutations = comb(n_dados, i)

        outcomes_success += one_permutation * n_permutations

    p = outcomes_success / outcomes_total

    return p * 100
```

These are some testing results

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: f_sucessos is the number of faces in the dice that are considered success, for example if I want to know the chance of get a number bigger than 12 in a d20, f_sucessos would be 8.

Comment: And I tried to use your code, but if you change the number of faces it dont work too. With 6 faces, a common dice the chances go down in line 2 and its half of real chance in line 9 (9 dice rolling).

I want to visualize how odds are improved by adding dices to the pool and how is the difference of making this among different dice and success ranges.

Comment: Well, the problem seems more interesting to solve then:) I'm gonna think further on it. Please share the solution here if you find it earlier than anyone else.

Comment: Seems I've solved it:) Please test the function. Looking to feedback.

Comment: hello @Raibek, your approach to this problem is very interesting, I tested it, but I dont studied this way yet. I will try too, but before that I come to share the results.

First, it look still not working, The coin works well, but the dice of 6 or four faces dont.
I prepared 3 check images with the brute force process:

Comment: Sum of chances to at least 1 face successful (fs) in 3d6
https://imgur.com/b3bVDOV

Sum of chances to at least 1 face successful (fs) in 4d6
https://imgur.com/TIwfFhR

Sum of chances to at least 1 face successful (fs) in 5d6
https://imgur.com/rupSeYD

Comment: So as you can see the results to 5 dice are not the same, and I will investigate the motive after.

But first as you can see my fisrt code is based on this method, and it hass been inproved. I will continue in the next answer, because coments restricted my char limit.

''

Answer (score 0):

Now my code, based on the images I posted is the sum of all exact chances to find the chance of at least 1 result.
Below the code I will comment the changes.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def dado(fs=1,ft=6,d=1,ns=1,exato=False):
  '''
  fs = faces success
  ft = faces totals
  d  = n of dice rolled
  ns - n of expected success
  exato = True: chance of exact ns events, False: chance of at least ns events
  '''
  s = Decimal(str(fs/ft))
  f = Decimal(str((ft-fs)/ft))
  d_int = d
  d = Decimal(str(d))
  ns = Decimal(str(ns))

  p_max = Decimal(str(s))**Decimal(str(d))

  fator = 1
  po_soma = 0

  for i in range(d_int-1):
    po = (Decimal(str(s))**(Decimal(str(d))-fator) * Decimal(str(f))**(Decimal(str(d))-(Decimal(str(d))-fator)))*Decimal(str(d))
    
    po_soma += po
    if exato == True:
      p_max = 0
      break
    fator += 1

  return f'{(p_max + po_soma)*100:.2f}%'

dado(1,2,5,1)
```

First -  not a change, it still dont work well.

Second -  I'm using now 'fs' variable to number of faces that means success and 'ns' variable to elaborate how many successes we gonna find, so fs = 1 and ns 2 in 3d6 means 'the chance of find at least 2 of 1 specific face rolling 3 dice'.

Third - I'm using Decimal because I realize that the multiplication of fractions could generate very small numbers and the precision could be affected by this (but it dont solve the initial problem, them Decimal may be quicked out soon).

Fourth - Exato (exact) is now a variable that breaks the loop and send to us just the 'exact value' or the 'at least ns value'. So 'exato=True' means in the last example 'the chance of find exact 2 of 1 specific face rolling 3 dice', a very smaller number.

This is it, my thanks for @Raibek that is trying solve this problem in combinations way, I'll study this way too but if you have an idea about please let me know.